# How to get info from a .json file discord.py

Tags: json, discord, discord.py

i wanted to make a bot that has customizeable welcome message where you use a command and you type #(the channel) and the message after. Problem is, in the on_member_join event i don't know how to make
`guild = (the guild that the command was ran in)`
or
`channel = (the channel the user put in)`
or
`message = (the message the user gave)`
all the information is in a json file called welcomemsgs.json. I just need to get the information from the .json file somehow. This is what an example of what the json file looks like `{"channel": 896476418421178397, "message": "Welcome!", "guild": 896476417968205894 }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy actually and if you are a beginner you can use json

first of all you create the command

```
@bot.command()
async def welcomechannel(ctx, channel):
    ch = int(channel.strip) # This removes the <#> and leaves the channel id
    with open('yourfilename.json', 'r') as f: # 'r' stands for read mode
        welcomes = json.load(f)

    welcomes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = ch # Sets the key to the channel

    with open('yourfilename.json', 'w') as f: # 'w' stands for write mode
        json.dump(welcomes, f) # Dumps the new data in the file
```

Then you do

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('yourfilename.json', 'r') as f:
        welcomes = json.load(f)
    channel = bot.get_channel(welcomes[str(member.guild.id)]
    await channel.send("Welcome " + member.mention)
```

Comment: and if i wanna make it more customizable like a customizable message where you can customize the message in the command?

Comment: It gives me an error saying i cant use some built in method 

ch = int(channel.strip)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: I could help you more with an postgresql database if you had one :( You can add me on discord tho so i can help you more Haxzyq#7049